# AJAX instant check with php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am developing a little webiste where I need to handle User registration. As usual, if a user requests a username that is already being used, the system should not allow to proceed with the registration.

I want to verify that during the register as most modern websites do. How do I do that using AJAX?

Register form:

```
<div class="container">
        <form id="register_form" action="actions/register_action.php" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name_area">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username_area">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username_id" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email_area">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pass_area">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="conf_pass_area">Confirm password</label>
                <input type="password" name="conf_pass_area" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="button_area" placeholder="Submit">
                <!--action to:register_action!-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </form> 
    </div>
```

users.php (where I do my php function regarding users):

```
<?php
    //checks if username inserted is already in use
    function check_username($username_pretended) {
        global $conn;

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM CommonUsers WHERE username=?');
        $stmt->execute(array($username_pretended));

        $res = $stmt->fetch();

        if($res['username'] == "") {
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }

    //inserts an user in the database
    function insertUser($name, $username, $email, $password) {
        global $conn;

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO CommonUsers(name, username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $stmt->execute(array($name, $username, $email, $password));
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. What part of "doing this using ajax" are you having a problem with?

Comment: @Mike you are right I should've been a little bit more explicit. I understand how AJAX does the instant checking, but I can not figure out the syntax, or how to organize the files and what to do after getting the response from AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From top of my head:

```
$("#username_id").on("change", function() 
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        method: "get", // or maybe post?
        url: "yoururlhere",
        data: 
        {
            username: $(this).val()
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            if (data == "0")
            {
                // Hide warning
            }
            else
            {
                // Warn user that username is already taken
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is the most simple way of doing this. Its sending the username to a server url for checking. Of course you will need an element to show the warning(which I could not find in your DOM).

You can check the [`ajax() method docs`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for detailed options.

In your PHP file:

```
$username = $_GET["username"];

if (check_username($username))
{
    return "1";
}
else 
{
    return "0";
}
```

Comment: So I would not be able to use my php file? I would have to create a new one exclusively to handle the AJAX call?

Comment: @CarlosPereira I can use your php file, but you'll need to know that the request was made to check the username only. And you have to call you function `check_username()` in some way and return the value to the request.

Comment: I know that, so it is easier to have a file just for the ajax call. God damn it this is killing me

Comment: @CarlosPereira I think so, instead of messing up an existent file which holds another logic, e.g. receiving form data to persist.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but I have several templates where I've structured my HTML, where would you advise me to store the jquery script?

Comment: @CarlosPereira no problem man. Well, there are some options. As it is made only for the register page, you can leave it directly on the page, but if you don't like that and want to make things clear, you can create a script file for your page only and include it.

Comment: So if I have a template with the header, I can leave it there, and then when including the header, the script will load up, whithout problems?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77654/discussion-between-carlos-pereira-and-dontvotemedown).

Comment: You can include it, but you'll need to add it on [`$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event. I can't chat now, I'm leaving my work.